# (Capybara) access modal window

Tags: javascript, capybara, modal-window

I am writing request specs ... I use Capybara... And I am in trouble with some modal windows.

What I actually want in my test is to fill in a form that pops up in a modal window.

The modal is created with Bootstrap from Twitter (http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals)... and it's going through a set of transitions (but I don't know if this is relevant to what I'm about to say).

I have tried a few workarounds I found on the web, like:

A) switching between pages with `page.driver.browser.window_handles`

```
page.driver.browser.switch_to.window(page.driver.browser.window_handles.last)
```

B) using `wait_until` to make sure that the modal loads

```
def modal_wrapper_id
  '#modal-edit'
end

def modal_visible
  wait_until { find(modal_wrapper_id).visible? }
rescue Capybara::TimeoutError
  flunk 'Expected modal to be visible.'
end
```

but none of those worked... so I thought to render the number of window handles at the moment when the modal window is active...

So I did this:

```
puts page.driver.browser.window_handles.length.should == 2
```

And I got this:

```
Failure/Error: page.driver.browser.window_handles.length.should == 2
           expected: 2
           got: 1 (using ==)
```

From what I understand, practically my modal window doesn't exist.

Any help on this one would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't use Capybara, but your problem has to do with the fact that Bootstrap's modal dialog is actually a pseudo-modal, in that it's actually just a `div` element and a transparent overlay behind it. A true modal dialog would be one created using `window.confirm`, for example, which can indeed be queried using your sample code. In your case you should give the modal `div` element an `id`, and use that as a handle to query it from Capybara and wait until its display is "block". Didn't test anything though.

Answer (score 1):

Capybara by default uses :rack_test driver. Can you confirm you're using Selenium WebDriver or other driver where opening a modalbox is actually possible?

Comment: I am using Selenium! `Capybara.default_driver = :selenium`

Comment: Ok, you have not mentioned this in your post. Since I don't see anything wrong, I would make sure that you really invoke that pop-up in your test suite (by clicking something, etc, I don't know the business logic). Also you can put some sleep 10 after that 'invoking pop-up' action, just for testing purposes.

Comment: I did put some `sleep` actions in my spec and I've tested it in many ways... and, as you said, I don't see anything wrong either... But still, I get the specified error, meaning the handle to that modal window doesn't exist, thus the window doesn't exist.

Comment: I'm getting the same with with Selenium - If i put a breakpoint I can see the modal isn't popping - were you able to resolve it?